# I'm trying to sort strings using merge sort

Tags: c, string, sorting, struct, mergesort

**Problem Statement**

> In this problem we have given a text document **employee.txt** in which employee names and their ages are stored, such as this data:
>
> ```
> abc 45
> xyz 23
> pqr 23
> xuv 25
> tcs 76
> ```
>
> And we have to sort this on string i.e. on names using merge sort and store them into new text document called **sorted_name_employee.txt**.

I have tried something but this is not giving an appropriate output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct employee
{
    char name[10];
    int age;
} emp[20];

void m_sort(struct employee *a, int low, int up);
void merge(struct employee *a, struct employee *temp, int low1, int up1, int low2, int up2);
int total_records(struct employee *a);
void copy(struct employee *a, struct employee *temp, int low, int up);
void write_into_file(struct employee *a, int n);

int main()
{
    int i = 0, n;
    struct employee emp[20];
    n = total_records(emp);
    //printf("n in main:- %d\n", n);
    m_sort(emp, 0, n - 1);
    /*for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %d\n", emp[i].name, emp[i].age);
    }*/
    write_into_file(emp, n);
    printf("Data has been written into 'sorted_name_emp.txt'");
}

int total_records(struct employee *a)
{
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("employee.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        while (!feof(fp))
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%s %d", a[i].name, &a[i].age);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return (i - 1);
}

void m_sort(struct employee *a, int low, int up)
{
    int mid;
    struct employee temp_emp[20];
    if (low < up)
    {
        mid = (low + up) / 2;
        m_sort(a, low, mid);
        m_sort(a, mid + 1, up);
        merge(a, temp_emp, low, mid, mid + 1, up);
        copy(a, temp_emp, low, up);
    }
}

void merge(struct employee *a, struct employee *temp, int low1, int up1, int low2, int up2)
{
    int i = low1, j = low2, k = low1;
    while ((i <= up1) && (j <= up2))
    {
        if (strcmp(a[i].name, a[j].name) <= 0)
        {
            strcpy(temp[k].name, a[i].name);
            temp[k].age = a[i].age;
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(temp[k].name, a[j].name);
            temp[k].age = a[j].age;
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    while (i <= up1)
    {
        strcpy(temp[k].name, a[i].name);
        temp[k].age = a[i].age;
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while (j <= up2)
    {
        strcpy(temp[k].name, a[j].name);
        temp[k].age = a[j].age;
        k++;
        j++;
    }
}

void copy(struct employee *a, struct employee *temp, int low, int up)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= up; i++)
    {
        strcpy(a[i].name, temp[i].name);
        a[i].age = temp[i].age;
    }
}

void write_into_file(struct employee *a, int n)
{
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("sorted_name_emp.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%s %d\n", a[i].name, a[i].age);
    }
}
```

Actual Ouptput in **sorted_name_emp.txt**:

```
abc 45
pqr 23
xuv 25
xyz 56
tcs 76
```

Comment: [`while(!feof(fp))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong).  Instead, check the return values of your `fscanf` to determine whether they (fully) succeeded.

Comment: For copying the temp array back to the main array, I would suggest a single call to `memcpy()` instead of the loop you are presently using.

Comment: And in `merge()`, I would use (whole-)structure assignment instead of member-by-member assignment / copying.

Comment: Note that you declare a global array, `emp`, of `struct employee`, but never use it.  The main array you do use (also named `emp`) is local to `main`.

Comment: With all that said, your program is not producing for me the result you claim it does for you. It seems to have an off-by-one error in the record count, but it is sorting the records into the correct order. Do you understand that the appearances of \n in the example data are meant to be understood as representing newline characters, not literal backslash / lowercase-'n' pairs?

Comment: ... and that off-by-one is in `write_into_file`, not in the actual sort.

Comment: The sort seems to work as expected. write_into_file() tries to write 6 records when there are actually 5 because you have "i<=n" in the "for" loop. It should be "i<n".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- if `n` is the number of records, `for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)` iterates one time too many.  You should use `i < n` instead of `i <= n`.
- `while (!feof(fp))` is always wrong to read and parse a file. Use this instead:

  ```
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d", a[i].name, &a[i].age) == 2) {
        i++;
    }
  ```
- `total_records` returns `i - 1`, which is cumbersome and error prone. You should just return `i` and fix the code elsewhere to handle `n` as the number of records.
- `m_sort(emp, 0, n - 1);` seems incorrect, but your implementation of `m_sort()` does assume that the last argument is the index to the last element. So it would be correct if `n` was the number of elements but since you return `i - 1` in `total_records`, you actually pass the index to the element before the last one, so this is the reason the last element is not sorted correctly.
- `mid = (low + up) / 2;` does not pose a problem for just a few records, but if sorting a large array, `low + up` could exceed the range of type `int` and cause undefined behavior.  You should write `mid = low + (up - low) / 2;`
- the loop in function `copy` iterates from `i=0`, whereas it should start at `i = low`.
- you forget to close the file in `total_records` and `write_into_file` with `fclose(fp)`
- `struct employee emp[20];` defined in `main` actually shadows the global array `emp[20]` defined at the global scope with the same name.
- there is no need to copy each structure member separately, you can just copy the structures directly with `temp[k] = a[i];`...

Passing the index to the last element is error prone. It is more idiomatic in C and less error prone to pass the index to the element past the end of the slice to sort.  This avoids cumbersome and confusing `+1` / `-1` adjustments.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct employee {
    char name[10];
    int age;
};

void m_sort(struct employee *a, int low, int up);
void merge(struct employee *a, struct employee *temp, int low1, int up1, int low2, int up2);
int total_records(struct employee *a, int max_index, const char *filename);
void copy(struct employee *a, struct employee *temp, int low, int up);
void write_into_file(struct employee *a, int n, const char *filename);

int main(void) {
    struct employee emp[20];
    int n = total_records(emp, 20, "employee.txt");
    m_sort(emp, 0, n);
    write_into_file(emp, n, "sorted_name_emp.txt");
    printf("Data has been written into 'sorted_name_emp.txt': %d lines\n", n);
    return 0;
}

int total_records(struct employee *a, int max_index, const char *filename) {
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    while (i < max_index && fscanf(fp, "%9s %d", a[i].name, &a[i].age) == 2) {
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return i;
}

void m_sort(struct employee *a, int low, int up) {
    if (up - low > 1) {
        struct employee temp_emp[20];
        int mid = low + (up - low) / 2;
        m_sort(a, low, mid);
        m_sort(a, mid, up);
        merge(a, temp_emp, low, mid, mid, up);
        copy(a, temp_emp, low, up);
    }
}

void merge(struct employee *a, struct employee *temp, int low1, int up1, int low2, int up2)
{
    int i = low1, j = low2, k = low1;
    while (i < up1 && j < up2) {
        if (strcmp(a[i].name, a[j].name) <= 0) {
            temp[k++] = a[i++];
        } else {
            temp[k++] = a[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < up1) {
        temp[k++] = a[i++];
    }
    while (j < up2) {
        temp[k++] = a[j++];
    }
}

void copy(struct employee *a, struct employee *temp, int low, int up) {
    for (int i = low; i < up; i++) {
        a[i] = temp[i];
    }
}

void write_into_file(struct employee *a, int n, const char *filename) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fprintf(fp, "%s %d\n", a[i].name, a[i].age);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Output file contents:

```
abc 45
pqr 23
tcs 76
xuv 25
xyz 23
```